# Regex that captures the text only if there is 3 lines

Tags: regex

I have this regex1 :

```
(\w+)\n#(\w+)_(\w+)\n(\w+)
```

That captures the following text1 :

```
randomtext
#randomteeexxt_randomqlsdfjml
randomagain
```

But sometimes I have a fourth line in the text2 :

```
randomtext
#randomteeexxt_randomqlsdfjml
randomagain
stillrandom
```

So this following regex2 works :

```
(\w+)\n#(\w+)_(\w+)\n(\w+)\n(\w+)
```

The regex2 does not match anything of the text1, this is what I want.

The regex1 matches the 3 first lines of the text2, but I don't want it.

I want that the regex1 does not match anything of the text2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try placing anchors around your current pattern to ensure that it applies to the entire input:

```
^(\w+)\n#(\w+)_(\w+)\n(\w+)$
```

Here is an example of how to use this pattern in JavaScript:

```js
var str_pass = 'AAA\n#BBB_CCC\nDDD';
var str_fail = 'AAA\n#BBB_CCC\nDDD\nEEE';
console.log(/^\w+\n#\w+_\w+\n\w+$/.test(str_pass));
console.log(/^\w+\n#\w+_\w+\n\w+$/.test(str_fail));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It does not work. It still captures the 3 first lines. I'm using https://regex101.com to test.

Comment: @GF `It does not work` ... that totally depends on what your definition of the word `it` is.  It doesn't work in the demo site, because that regex tool is designed to be applied as many times as possible.  However, in most programming languages, the anchors I added would ensure that the _entire_ input matches the pattern.  So, what tool/language are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry for long answer, had to double check with my dev. We're using JavaScript, Node JS. Do you need more info ?

Comment: Include your current JS code, and also state why my pattern is not working with it.

Comment: const str = 'AAA\n#BBB_CCC\nDDD\nEEE';
const ret = str.match(/^\w+\n#\w+_\w+\n\w+$/m);
console.log(ret);

Comment: [ 'AAA\n#BBB_CCC\nDDD',
  index: 0,
  input: 'AAA\n#BBB_CCC\nDDD\nEEE',
  groups: undefined ]

Comment: I'm waiting to have the Null result. Here it still takes the 3 first lines.

Comment: @GF Check my updated answer, which now includes a JavaScript code sample.  You should be using `test()` to check if an input string matches a regex pattern.